# Image path not convert to url in swift3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, uiimageview

I have post response i want to download image from `image_path`

```
let fileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: (posts.value(forKey: "image_path") as! [String])[indexPath.row])
        print(fileUrl as Any) // here i can get path

        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: (fileUrl)// nil value {
            let url = NSURL(string: (posts.value(forKey: "image_path") as! [String])[indexPath.row]) // Here url found nil
            let data = NSData(contentsOf: url! as URL)
            cell.LocationImage?.image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
        }
```

UPDATE:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWC]S9.png

Comment: check out my answer with afnetworking 3.0 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36007238/afnetworking-3-0-cant-download-image/39695800#39695800 or you can use sd webimage for downloading image. If your url is external from server

Comment: @ViralRathod your image_path is URL in post response??

Comment: @TusharSharma posts is my response from soap, 'posts.value(forKey: "image_path") as! [String])[indexPath.row]'

Comment: @ViralRathod i mean what is the value for key "image_path".Is it a URL??

Comment: @TusharSharma its url string path http:/sf.iipl.info/ImageCSharp.aspx%3FLocation=C:%5C%5Cinfinityhost%5C%5Cdemo11.iipl.info%5C%5Cdata%5C%5Capp%5C%5Cuser_location_photo%5C%5C8000034939_Resize%5C%5C&FileName=1_35f28e55-ca31-4918-8b41-9eb7f3070ace -- file:///

Comment: This is my response string == http://sf.iipl.info/ImageCSharp.aspx?Location=C:\\infinityhost\\demo11.iipl.info\\data\\app\\user_location_photo\\8000034939_Resize\\&FileName=1_35f28e55-ca31-4918-8b41-9eb7f3070ace

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show image from the imagePath in swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44363372/how-to-show-image-from-the-imagepath-in-swift3)

Comment: Why are you using nsurl? Use URL with swift and you need to cast.

Comment: Oops. You won't need to cast.

Answer (score 0):

That URL is not a local file path URL, nor a valid URL accoridng to my browser.

The URL you have provided above returns a server error in the browser and does not return an image. See screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

You would need to ensure that the image is accessible and the URL actually returns an image response firstly. Then you would need to download the image. Not sure if you are using any libraries or not so I will post an example without.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import XCPlayground
import PlaygroundSupport

let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))

// random image from images.google.com
let urlString = "https://files.allaboutbirds.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/prow-featured-240x135.jpg"

let url = URL(string: urlString)
let session = URLSession.shared

let task = session.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
    guard error == nil else {
        print("[ERROR] - Failed to download image")
        return
    }

    if let data = data {
        let image = UIImage(data: data)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            imageView.image = image
        }
    }
}

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
view.addSubview(imageView)

task.resume()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

UPDATE:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: This is my response URL "http://sf.iipl.info/ImageCSharp.aspx?Location=C:\\infinityhost\\demo11.iipl.info\\data\\app\\user_location_photo\\8000034939_Resize\\&FileName=1_35f28e55-ca31-4918-8b41-9eb7f3070ace"

Comment: try it in browser... does it show an image or a server error?

Comment: when you paste in browser it directly Download image and that image i can open in preview

Comment: see my updated answer. The image is on a remote server, a File URL is supposed to be for a local resource as far as I am aware. Ensure that the URL works and try my code above. see if it works

Comment: please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44327312/sort-my-tableviewcell-with-distance-comes-from-response-in-swift3 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44363372/how-to-show-image-from-the-imagepath-in-swift3  please if you can help more

Comment: You shouldn't duplicate questions. I've updated my answer. I have the image showing with the URL provided in your second link above.

Comment: please see my screenshot

Comment: above the line starting `let task =  ` add `print(url)`. The only thing that could be nil there is the URL but I have the exact same code and its fine for me?. or preferably use a breakpoint to see what the value is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145879/discussion-between-viralrathod-and-scriptable).

Comment: found nil my friend value is nil also